# Calculating the values of my form with a button

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

As one of my first projects i am working on a form to calculate "money straps" by using the selected form "type='radio'". What i am looking to do is take the selected inputs and calculate them when the "buy" button is selected. i would imagine it would take a function to make this possible i just have no idea where to start and how to implement the values into this calculation. The only thing i'm aware of is that the math should be "(denom * strap) * times". Anyplace to get started would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance and sorry if i was not specific enough but i hope what i am trying to do is understood. As of right now i have no javascript written just the HTML setup.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <h1 id='header'>
            <b>BUY MONEY</b>
        </h1>
    </head>

    <body id='body'>

        <form id='strapDenom'>
            <p id='p1'>
                <b>DENOMINATION</b>
            </p>
            <input type='radio' name='denom' value='100' checked> 1's<br>
            <input type='radio' name='denom' value='200'> 2's<br>
            <input type='radio' name='denom' value='500'> 5's<br>
            <input type='radio' name='denom' value='1000'> 10's<br>
            <input type='radio' name='denom' value='2000'> 20's<br>
            <input type='radio' name='denom' value='1000'> 50's<br>
            <input type='radio' name='denom' value='1000'> 100's<br>
        </form>

        <form id='strapCount'>
            <p id='p2'>
                <b>STRAP COUNT</b>
            </p>
            <input type='radio' name='strap' value='1' checked> 1<br>
            <input type='radio' name='strap' value='2'> 2<br>
            <input type='radio' name='strap' value='3'> 3<br>
            <input type='radio' name='strap' value='4'> 4<br>
            <input type='radio' name='strap' value='5'> 5<br>
            <input type='radio' name='strap' value='6'> 6<br>
            <input type='radio' name='strap' value='7'> 7<br>
            <input type='radio' name='strap' value='8'> 8<br>
            <input type='radio' name='strap' value='9'> 9<br>
            <input type='radio' name='strap' value='10'> 10<br>
        </form>

        <form id='multiply'>
            <p id='p3'>
                <b>MULTIPLE</b>
            </p>
            <input type='radio' name='times' value='1' checked> 1<br>
            <input type='radio' name='times' value='2'> 2<br>
            <input type='radio' name='times' value='3'> 3<br>
            <input type='radio' name='times' value='4'> 4<br>
            <input type='radio' name='times' value='5'> 5<br>
            <input type='radio' name='times' value='6'> 6<br>
            <input type='radio' name='times' value='7'> 7<br>
            <input type='radio' name='times' value='8'> 8<br>
            <input type='radio' name='times' value='9'> 9<br>
            <input type='radio' name='times' value='10'> 10<br>
        </form>

        <br>

        <button id='buy' onclick=''>BUY</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

would i use something like this?

```
function buyMoney() {
    var den = document.getElementById('denom').value;
    var str = document.getElementById('strap').value;
    var tim = document.getElementById('times').value;
document.getElementById('buy').innerHTML = den * str * tim;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any Javascript, what have you tried? Do you have a specific question? SO isn't here to write your whole script for you

Comment: @CertainPerformance i understand that and im not looking to find an entire script. I just have no idea where to begin. I would imagine you would define the function containing the values from each i just can not find how to do that. Only looking for a place to get started, not the entire thing. Sorry if that came off that way. i've been googling for a while to try and find it. maybe use something like "var val = document.getElementById("xxx").value;" ? im not sure

Answer (score 1):

Try with below solution,

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <h1 id='header'>
    <b>BUY MONEY</b>
  </h1>
  <script>
    function calculate() {
      var denom = $("input[name='denom']:checked").val();
      var strap = $("input[name='strap']:checked").val();
      var times = $("input[name='times']:checked").val();
      var finalPrice = (denom * strap) * times;
      $("#iblFinalPrice").html(finalPrice);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body id='body'>
  <form id='strapDenom'>
    <p id='p1'>
      <b>DENOMINATION</b>
    </p>
    <input type='radio' name='denom' value='100' checked> 1's<br>
    <input type='radio' name='denom' value='200'> 2's<br>
    <input type='radio' name='denom' value='500'> 5's<br>
    <input type='radio' name='denom' value='1000'> 10's<br>
    <input type='radio' name='denom' value='2000'> 20's<br>
    <input type='radio' name='denom' value='1000'> 50's<br>
    <input type='radio' name='denom' value='1000'> 100's<br>
  </form>
  <form id='strapCount'>
    <p id='p2'>
      <b>STRAP COUNT</b>
    </p>
    <input type='radio' name='strap' value='1' checked> 1<br>
    <input type='radio' name='strap' value='2'> 2<br>
    <input type='radio' name='strap' value='3'> 3<br>
    <input type='radio' name='strap' value='4'> 4<br>
    <input type='radio' name='strap' value='5'> 5<br>
    <input type='radio' name='strap' value='6'> 6<br>
    <input type='radio' name='strap' value='7'> 7<br>
    <input type='radio' name='strap' value='8'> 8<br>
    <input type='radio' name='strap' value='9'> 9<br>
    <input type='radio' name='strap' value='10'> 10<br>
  </form>
  <form id='multiply'>
    <p id='p3'>
      <b>MULTIPLE</b>
    </p>
    <input type='radio' name='times' value='1' checked> 1<br>
    <input type='radio' name='times' value='2'> 2<br>
    <input type='radio' name='times' value='3'> 3<br>
    <input type='radio' name='times' value='4'> 4<br>
    <input type='radio' name='times' value='5'> 5<br>
    <input type='radio' name='times' value='6'> 6<br>
    <input type='radio' name='times' value='7'> 7<br>
    <input type='radio' name='times' value='8'> 8<br>
    <input type='radio' name='times' value='9'> 9<br>
    <input type='radio' name='times' value='10'> 10<br>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div> <b>Total Price :</b> <label id="iblFinalPrice"></label></div>
  <br>
  <button id='buy' onclick='calculate()'>BUY</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: here you get the value inside the lable, If you dont want to print that in lable the directly stored that value in some variable then use that variable with your further function implementation. This is the way you start up with calculating the values, Let me know still you have any queries. :)

Comment: code works great with that! thanks.  Would there be a way to do it without the External src tho or do i need to use it? I'm trying to learn the base of javascript without anything extra for the moment.

Comment: @j D, kindly accept it as a answer then :) and let me know if you are at stuck at any level happy to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var form = document.getElementById("strapDenom");
alert(form.elements["denom"].value);
var denom = form.elements["denom"].value;
var strap= form.elements["strap"].value;
var times= form.elements["times"].value;
var multiple = denom*strap*times;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your own function is right, you just have to add
    `var result = denom*strap*times`
and `result` should contain your result. Add your OP, or whatever you want to do with the result, to the function, add the function on the top of the HTML, e.g. right above your form, and trigger your function in the button.

Comment: would it look like this?          "function buyMoney() {
 var den = document.getElementById('denom').value;
 var str = document.getElementById('strap').value;
 var tim = document.getElementById('times').value;
 var result = den * str *tim;
document.getElementById('buy').innerHTML = result;
}"      as for adding it to the top im using jsfiddle to practice so the code is implemented separately (externally) if thats what you meant.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, was very busy. Yes, it would look like that. I meant you should define your function at the top of your HTML, or if it's in a seperate file, just set a link in the <head> as you normally would.